# Neural Network with tensorflow recall over 100

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, precision-recall

I am trying to get all metrics for created model:

```
def build_rnn_gru_model(tokenizer):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, 64,input_length=863),
        tf.keras.layers.GRU(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',f1,precision, recall])
    return model
```

I have also used the metrics definitions suggested in the highly upvoted answer in [How to get accuracy, F1, precision and recall, for a keras model?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45165/how-to-get-accuracy-f1-precision-and-recall-for-a-keras-model), but the results were the same:

```
def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(y_pred) * y_true)
    possible_positives = K.sum(y_true)
    return true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())


def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision


def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    precision_ = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    recall_ = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision_*recall_)/(precision_+recall_+K.epsilon()))
```

While evaluating models with `LSTM` or with no recurrent layers everything looks ok, but with `GRU` recal value is incredible high:

```
 199/1180 [====>.........................] - ETA: 4:45 - loss: 0.3988 - accuracy: 0.8230 - f1: 1.6155 - precision: 0.8195 - recall: 468.6583
```

could anyone give me a hint what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with TF 2 I suggest you use the predefined [metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall), in your case `tf.keras.metrics.Recall`

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(), ...])
```

I suggest setting `return_sequences=False` in your GRU layer because I'm thinking you are carrying out a binary classification task

Comment: I use `tensorflow==2.2.0rc3` and using `tf.keras.metrics.Recall()` couse me to get tonz of errors like `assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
    ValueError: Shapes (None, 863) and (None, 1) are incompatible`

Comment: @Mithrand1r indeed, this mighty be the issue; in general, when using the predefined functions and getting such errors/warnings, you should be suspicious of your actual predictions instead of dumping the functions and trying to do the job "manually".